# How to show sync failed message

Tags: android, synchronization, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

I've build a contacts sync adapter. It's all working fine but I need one more thing. If for some reason the sync does not complete successfully, I want to show a message like Google account is showing when the sync fails

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So are you asking how to show this message, or which exceptions need to be catched in order to know the sync has failed?

Comment: I have `catch` blocks in the `onPerformSync` that's catching the exceptions, and in those blocks I have `syncResult.stats.numParseExceptions++` and `syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++`. I hope that this is the right way to catch the exceptions. If so, I need how to show the message

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to set the delay on the sync result. After this delay the sync will be restarted.

```
try {
    DO THE SYNCHRONIZATION
} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "AuthenticationException");
    syncResult.stats.numAuthExceptions++;
    syncResult.delayUntil = 180;
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "ParseException");
    syncResult.stats.numParseExceptions++;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
    syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++;
    syncResult.delayUntil = 180;
}
```

Comment: It will show a message in the bottom of the screen like the one on the picture, and will retry the sync after the amount of seconds specified with `syncResult.delayUntil = numOfSeconds;`

Answer (score -3):

I think what you want are [Toasts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Simple Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

`text` is, as you can imagine, the text you want to be displayed.
`duration` is either Toast.LENGTH_SHORT or Toast.LENGTH_LONG (depends in how long the Toast sahll be visible)

More complicated approach with picture in the toast: (sync_toast_lo.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/SynctoastLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/your_logo"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:id="@+id/syncLogo">
  </ImageView>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/syncFailedText"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="The sync has failed!"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white">
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Sync_toast_lo,
                               (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.SynctoastLayout));

Toast toast = new Toast(this);
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```

Comment: NO, I don't want toast. I know very good what a toast is. I want to show a message in accounts and sync exactly as the Google account shows a message when the sync fails

Comment: shouldn't have been downvoted...  The only problem with a toast is that it's in a non-activity class in the SyncAdapter.java

Comment: + sync is executed in the background and showing a toast from bg doesn't work.